# Presigned_url with post - method not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elixir, pre-signed-url

I am trying to use the [`ExAws.S3.presign_url/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_s3/ExAws.S3.html#presigned_url/5) method on the `ex_aws_s3` package.

Long story short - regardless of what url I use or options… I just cannot get this function to play ball even with postman let alone trying to send data from the browser as a form object.

[image] (response , headers and url1)

[image] (response , headers and url2)

my function:

```
  def presign_post_url(bucket_name, file_name, file_type_extension) do                                            config = % 
     config = { region: "eu-west-1" }
     ex_s3_client = ExAws.Config.new(:s3, config)
     query_params = [
        { "Content-Type", "image/jpg"},                                                                               
        {'key', "profile-pictures/" <> file_name}                                                                     
        # { "content-length-range", "10\,10000000" }#max 10MB
     ]                                                                                                             
    presign_options = [virtual_host: false, query_params: query_params]                                                                                                                                                       

    ExAws.S3.presigned_url(ex_s3_client, :post, "profile-pictures", file_name, presign_options)                                                                                                                               
  end
```

Which returns something like:

```
https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/profile-pictures/67641eaf-4e3e-4792-98da-8df533605cd2.jpg?Content-Type=image%2Fjpg&key=profile-pictures%2F67641eaf-4e3e-4792-98da-8df533605cd2.jpg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXHBL256UAYWNNMAO%2F20200404%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200404T034332Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1fcb3ebd678ea2f26cee5709004914cb3c7bc057c7ba164cdba160eec999cbb1
```

The error I get - not matter how I construct the url with bucket_name/folder-path/differents3-url-structures, I always get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
    <Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
    <Method>POST</Method>
    <ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
    <RequestId>D0BA0AC513BE36D6</RequestId>
    <HostId>NyzdUPLDzHnbkHzWxxcLjdGXOXkpmGOUU1KFIAPJ+vpIPEq0WWyZEerGq1xySG26qzPfKUg7l/o=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Cors on bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I am stumped.

Also - this WORKS with PUT.. just not POST. I read something about the post really being redirected to a put but you need to have the right url.

2 kinds of urls to s3

`https:/bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.coms/folder_where_file_is/file_nmae.jpg` 
and then you pass the region in the config.

or

`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/folder_where_file_is/file_nmae.jpg`

I showed this in screenshots - still not working.

Comment: What would a call to `ExAws.S3.presigned_url(ex_s3_client, :post, "profile-pictures", file_name, presign_options)` return? Simply wrap it into `IO.inspect()` and post the result here. Also, please never post screenshots, post plain text.

Comment: updated the question: essentially the function returns the url I am using in those postman requests.

Comment: Any update?  If so, can you please add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the URL you use (truncated for the clarity):

```
https://s3/folder/file_name.jpg?query
```

The Restful API distinguishes `POST` requests to *create* new resources vs `PUT` requests to *update* existing resources.

`POST`s are supposed to be made to the *folder*. `PUT`s, on contrary, are done to the *resource id*.

That said, both below would be correct:

```
POST /folder/
PUT /folder/file_name.jpg
```

None is what you actually issue, which is an attempt to `POST` to the `resource id`.

I am not sure about the exact correct way of uploading a file, but the URL you need must lack the file name, so somewhat along the lines below should work.

```rb
ExAws.S3.presigned_url(
  ex_s3_client,
  :post, 
  "profile-pictures",
  nil,
  presign_options
)
```

Maybe the object must be a file object itself, I am not sure.